# python openssl error when import requests and other packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, openssl

When I do one of the following imports or commands in python3 I get always the same error

```
import requests | from influxdb_client import InfluxDBClient | pip3 uninstall openssl | pip3 list
```

The error is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 46, in <module>
    import OpenSSL.SSL
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 16, in <module>
    from OpenSSL._util import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 6, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl.binding import Binding
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 15, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl import ffi, lib
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 88: invalid continuation byte
```

The code is not changed and the error is also present in other python scripts. The device is RPI3 with raspbian. The only thing that changed it that it was shipped to another country and connected to the network there for remote monitoring.

Thanks

Comment: your installation seems to be broken.  Purge and reinstall python using the system package manager.

Comment: @2e0byo I will try that. Thanks.